# Max date in columns

Tags: sql-server, date, max, where-clause

How would I best capture the latest start and end date (row 2) in my where statement?

```
 START_DATE    END_DATE
1 - 1/1/2017    9/30/2017
2- 10/1/2017    12/31/2017


Where start_date <= '2017-12-31' and end_date >= '2017-01-01'
```

Comment: use `ORDER BY START_DATE DESC`

Comment: where END_DATE = MAX(END_DATE)

Comment: You can either sort by start date or end date, but you can't make the first row have the max start date and the second row the max end date. If you meant column instead of row, you can do a `MAX(start_date)` and `MAX(end_date)`.

Comment: Unclear, what if the latest start date was on a different row from the latest end date?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am joining to this table where contract start and end dates reside.  I am currently looking to join to those that are in calendar year 2017 only.  However there are some that have multiple lines for the same year, so when I join I am duplicating values. Can we use max(start_date) and max(end_date) for calendar year 2017 only?  In the example above I am only want to join to row 2.

Answer (score 0):

You want `order by` clause instead of `where` clause :

```
select top 1 . . .
from . . 
order by start_date desc;
```